# Is there any way to use regex patterns in strip method

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings like this

```
...

'43.990\none of the things we notice\nis that the headers all have\n\n296\n',
'47.020\nthe word edit and\nbraces behind them,\n\n297\n',

...
```

I want only the text from the above list and not the starting numbers and \n. Is there anyway to strip with regex patterns like this

```
i.strip(r"[0-9.\\n]+")
```

This does not seem to work.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.sub` to replace characters that match your regex, with anchors to the beginning and ending of the line:

```py
i = re.sub('^[0-9.\n]+|[0-9.\n]+$', '', i, re.I)
```

Output (for your two sample pieces of data):

```
one of the things we notice
is that the headers all have
the word edit and
braces behind them,
```

Note I've assumed the `\n` in your data is an actual newline, if not (it is the literal string `\n`), you should use this instead:

```py
i = re.sub(r'^(?:[0-9.]|\\n)+|(?:[0-9.]|\\n)+$', '', i, re.I)
```

Output:

```
one of the things we notice\nis that the headers all have
the word edit and\nbraces behind them,
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```py
inp = ['43.990\none of the things we notice\nis that the headers all have\n\n296\n', '47.020\nthe word edit and\nbraces behind them,\n\n297\n']
output = [re.sub(r'\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*', ' ', x).strip() for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['one of the things we notice\nis that the headers all have',
 'the word edit and\nbraces behind them,']
```